# Can I define a mixin as the target of a relationship using declarative style

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this model which defines a mixin `OrbiterMixin` with a `parent` relationship. It is inherited by `CelestialBody` and `SpaceShip`. It is self-referential if one `CelestialBody` orbits another. Only a `CelestialBody` can have `children`, however, so that relationship is defined on that class. The declared type of the relationship is `Mapped[Optional[list[OrbiterMixin]]]` which is correct (conceptually) since all `children` of a `CelestialBody` must be of type `OrbiterMixin`.

However, SQLAlchemy complains about it not being mapped: `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'model.OrbiterMixin' is not mapped`.

How can I define the mixin as the type using declarative style?

```
from typing import Optional

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, declared_attr, mapped_column, relationship

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class OrbiterMixin:
    name: Mapped[str]
    parent_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("celestial_body.name"))

    @declared_attr
    def parent(cls) -> Mapped["CelestialBody"]:
        kwargs = {}
        if cls.__name__ == "CelestialBody":
            kwargs.update(remote_side=[cls.name])

        return relationship("CelestialBody", back_populates="children", lazy="joined", **kwargs)


class CelestialBody(Base, OrbiterMixin):
    __tablename__ = "celestial_body"

    children: Mapped[Optional[list[OrbiterMixin]]] = relationship(back_populates="parent", lazy="joined")


class SpaceShip(Base, OrbiterMixin):
    __tablename__ = "spaceship"
```